# How to implement next-previous buttons for images?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to implement a simple next-previous image preview with two buttons but the code below works only for 3 images. How to make it more dynamic for any number of images? I would appreciate any help.

```
private void left_arrow_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (x == custom_studio_images.Count - 2)
    {
        x = custom_studio_images.Count;
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        CustomStudio.Children.RemoveAt(LargePic.Children.Count);
        CustomStudio.Children.Add(custom_studio_images.ElementAt(x - 1));

    }

    else
    {
        CustomStudio.Children.RemoveAt(LargePic.Children.Count);
        CustomStudio.Children.Add(custom_studio_images.ElementAt(x - 2));
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());

        x--;
    }
}

private void right_arrow_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (CustomStudio.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        CustomStudio.Children.RemoveAt(LargePic.Children.Count); //clear first item in StackPanel
    }


    if (x == custom_studio_images.Count )
    {
        x = 0;
        CustomStudio.Children.Add(custom_studio_images.ElementAt(x));
        x++;
    }


    else
    {
        CustomStudio.Children.Add(custom_studio_images.ElementAt(x)); //show picture for next available studio in a set
        x++;

    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: No error. Its just the problem with previous button (left_arrow_btn_Click). If I have 10 images for example, and I hit to go back on 10th, then I go back down to 7 and cen go back forward again to 10, so it gets stuck like follows 10-7-10, or if I go up to 6 then 6-3-6. If you know what I mean lol

Comment: What is `LargePic.Children.Count`, does it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a MVVM solution with a view model that exposes a list of images, a current image, and two commands that navigate to the previous and next image:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        PreviousImageCommand = new RelayCommand(PreviousImage);
        NextImageCommand = new RelayCommand(NextImage);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand PreviousImageCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand NextImageCommand { get; set; }
    public List<ImageSource> Images { get; set; }

    public ImageSource CurrentImage
    {
        get
        {
            if (currentImageIndex < Images.Count)
            {
                return Images[currentImageIndex];
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    private int currentImageIndex;

    private void PreviousImage(object o)
    {
        if (Images.Count > 0)
        {
            // add Image.Count to avoid negative index
            currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + Images.Count - 1) % Images.Count;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentImage");
        }
    }

    private void NextImage(object o)
    {
        if (Images.Count > 0)
        {
            currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % Images.Count;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentImage");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You would now bind the properties of this view model in XAML like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage}"/>
...
<Button Content="Prev" Command="{Binding PreviousImageCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextImageCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general work with the number of images available.

And if you come past the last one, index the beginning with the modulo operator:

```
CustomStudio.Children.Add(custom_studio_images.ElementAt(x % custom_studio_images.Count));
```

The problematic part is your if-statement:

```
if (x == custom_studio_images.Count - 2)
{
    x = custom_studio_images.Count; ...
```

You're setting it back to the count once you hit `count - 2`. You never come below this point.

Comment: Actually, the code for Next button works for any number of images. The problem is with Previous (left_arrow_btn_Click). Which line should I replace with yours?

Comment: What do you want to do when you hit the zero index? Start from the end?

Comment: Yes. and when I hit the maximum to start form zero, which it does